# Spring 3, pass data from jsp to controller

Tags: java, ajax, spring, jquery, spring-mvc

I am using Spring 3. In my jsp I have a form

```
<form action='componentAction.html' method='POST'>
    <input type='hidden' id='action_' name='componentAction' value=""/>
</form>
```

The value of the form's action changes to either start, stop or pause.

I also have 3 buttons: start, stop and pause. Upon pressing one of these buttons the value of the form changes.

```
<input type="button" value="Start" onclick="changeFormValueAndSubmit('start')">
<input type="button" value="Stop" onclick="changeFormValueAndSubmit('stop')">
<input type="button" value="Pause" onclick="changeFormValueAndSubmit('pause')">
```

I would like to be able to send the value of the form to my controller via ajax call after the press happens.

Can someone please show me the right way of doing it? Alsos hould I use POST or GET?

I have tried following tutorials such as
http://www.raistudies.com/spring/spring-mvc/ajax-spring-mvc-3-annonations-jquery/
http://hmkcode.com/spring-mvc-json-json-to-java/
http://java.dzone.com/articles/using-spring-mvc%E2%80%99s
But I have failed miserably.

Thanks to anyone for their hlep in advance!

Comment: Can you show us what you tried?

Comment: All the links I posted I have tried. However they did not work because I could not receive the value I was sending.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using JQuery you can use the following in your changeFormValueAndSubmit() function

```
function changeFormValueAndSubmit(buttonName) {
   var formData = $('form').serialize();
   jQuery.post('/path', formData, function(d) {
         // handle response
   });

    ...
}
```

Note: that in this example, jquery will send **all** the data fields in your form.

Make your you include the jquery framework in your JSP and also have a controller method in spring to handle the POST.

POST is preferable over GET.

On server side using Spring 3 annotations, something like

```
@Controller
public class ExampleController {

    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value = "/path", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String post(@RequestParam String componentAction)  {
        // do work
        ...
        return "OK";  // depends on what you need to send back...
    }


}
```

You must enable MVC annotations. See http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/mvc.html#mvc-annotation-driven

Comment: This is awesome. Can you also please show me how I would receive it on the server side inside the controller?

Comment: Thank you :) This is what I was looking for and what other tutorials never said

Answer (score 0):

POST or GET will determine if the form data is sent encoded in the URL (GET) or in embedded in the http requests message body (POST). Since it is an ajax call, the URL will not be shown directly to the user, but either way, the user can see the contents of the request under the browser's developer tools.

The simplest way to get spring to direct traffic to your jsp is like such:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>MyJSPServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/urlFromOutside</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>MyJSPServlet</servlet-name>
    <jsp-file>/pathToJspFile/MyJspFile.jsp</jsp-file>
</servlet>
```

To get the form data, in your jsp file, you have access to the request object and can get the parameters like so:

```
<%= request.getParameter("componentAction") %>
```